# How do I change the query if I use the library nestjs-paginate?

Tags: javascript, mysql, npm, nestjs, nestjs-typeorm

I use the nestjs-paginated library from npm and I would like to modify the query so that the GET endpoint returns only a limited number of objects.

```
async findAll(query: PaginateQuery): Promise<Paginated<Repo>> {
        try {
          const options: PaginateConfig<Repo> = {
            sortableColumns: ['title'],
            searchableColumns: ['title'],
            relations: ['quiz', 'answers'],
            filterableColumns: {
              'quiz.id': [FilterOperator.EQ],
            },
          }

          return paginate(query, this.quizRepo, options)
        } catch (err) {
          throw new BadRequestException(`Failed to fetch quizzes: ${err.detail || err.message}`)
        }
      }
```

I would need the new query to be of this form:

```
SELECT *  FROM public."quiz-questions" WHERE "quizId" = '${quizId}' AND random() < 0.01 LIMIT 30
```